# Fixed header sort columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView that I need to have the headers fixed and each column sortable.
I am using ASP.NET and C#.

I found code to do this but I can't get the columns to sort at all. I have stepped thru this code and it is calling the Sort functions in the aspx file. When I clicked the sort buttons on the column headings, the display in the grid does not change (ascending/descending) sort order.  I am thinking it has something to do with the binding of the gridview with my data.

[Here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Scrollable-GridView-with-Fixed-Headers-and-Client-Side-Sorting-using-jQuery-in-ASP.Net.aspx) is the original code.

My version is below:
The Default.aspx is:
This header is copied from the original code.

```
<head runat="server">
<title>Create XML Files</title>
<script src="/scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery.tablesorter.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>").tablesorter();
        SetDefaultSortOrder();
    });

    function Sort(cell, sortOrder) {
        var sorting = [[cell.cellIndex, sortOrder]];
        $("#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>").trigger("sorton", [sorting]);
        if (sortOrder == 0) {
            sortOrder = 1;
            cell.className = "sortDesc";
        }
        else {
            sortOrder = 0;
            cell.className = "sortAsc";
        }
        cell.setAttribute("onclick", "Sort(this, " + sortOrder + ")");
        cell.onclick = function() { Sort(this, sortOrder); };
        document.getElementById("container").scrollTop = 0;
    }


    function SetDefaultSortOrder() {
        var gvHeader = document.getElementById("dummyHeader");
        var headers = gvHeader.getElementsByTagName("TH");
        for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
            headers[i].setAttribute("onclick", "Sort(this, 1)");
            headers[i].onclick = function() { Sort(this, 1); };
            headers[i].className = "sortDesc";
        }
    }
</script>

<style type = "text/css">
.sortAsc
{
    background-image: url(images/asc.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right;
    cursor: pointer;
    width:200px;
}
.sortDesc
{
    background-image: url(images/desc.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right;
    cursor: pointer;
    width:200px;
}
.grid THEAD
{
     background-color:Purple;
     color:White;
}
    .style1
    {
        width: 113px;
    }
    .style2
    {
        width: 152px;
    }
</style>
```

THis is the gridview part...

```
<div style =" background-color:Purple; height:30px;width:417px; margin:0;padding:0">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding = "0" rules="all" border="1" id="dummyHeader" 
style="font-family:Arial;font-size:10pt;width:417px;color:white;
border-collapse:collapse;height:100%;">
<tr>
    <th scope="col" style ="width:48px;text-align:center">Number</th>
    <th scope="col" style ="width:50px;text-align:center">District</th>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id = "container" style ="height:186px; width:435px; overflow:auto;">
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ShowHeader="False" AllowSorting="True" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass = "grid" CellPadding="3" ForeColor="White" 
    GridLines="None" Height="69px" Width="417px" BackColor="White" 
        BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderWidth="2px" CellSpacing="1" 
        style="margin-bottom: 0px">

    <RowStyle BackColor="#DEDFDE" ForeColor="Black" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Number" HeaderText = "Number" >
            <ItemStyle Width="50px" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="District" HeaderText = "District" >
            <ItemStyle Width="50px" />
        </asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#C6C3C6" ForeColor="Black" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#C6C3C6" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#9471DE" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4A3C8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#E7E7FF" />
</asp:GridView>
</div>
```

I create a datatable and bind it to the gridview:

```
//Create the data table
stationTable = new DataTable();
stationTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Number", typeof(int)));
stationTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("District", typeof(string)));

var query = from stations in xml.Elements("Config").Elements("distributedHost").Elements("station") 
                         select new 
                        {   
                            number = stations.Element("number").Value,
                            district = stations.Element("district").Value
                         } ;

            foreach (var row in query)
            {
                DataRow dataRow = stationTable.NewRow();

                dataRow[stationTable.Columns["Number"]] = row.number;
                dataRow[stationTable.Columns["District"]] = row.district;

                stationTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
            }
            GridView1.DataSource = stationTable;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you already use the new static client id´s for controls (seems to be default in visual studio 2012). So you could try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#GridView1").tablesorter();
    SetDefaultSortOrder();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But it did not change the results.  When I click the sort button on the column header, it updates the image but the sort data does not change.

Comment: I did not mention previously. But i am using Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: I am trying to learn how the javascript works...                  In the .trigger event, the first parameter 'sorton', is used. I did a search and javascript does not have 'sorton' as an event. Could this be the problem?

Comment: No, I think the sorton is some method that the tablesorter plugin assigns to the gridview to make it sort... have you debugged your javascript to see if the Sort method is called?

Answer (score 0):

I could not use this option because, it needed to sort the entire DataTable, not just the data that was displayed.
I found a great GridView that allowed me to do everything.
It can be found here:
http://ideasparks.codeplex.com/